# how does android handle font files?

Tags: android, android-fonts

What is the technical process behind using a .ttf or an .otf font file in Android? How does the system handle such files? That is well-known that android doesn't like certain fonts and we get a `native font cannot be made` error. I would like to create my own .ttf font using some tools and use that font in my app. But I'm not sure if android will accept those self-made fonts, so I'd be thankful for any answers to the questions asked above.

**UPDATE**

dudes, I know how to use fonts in Android, thanks :) I was asking about the technical process of the system decoding and handling the font files.. Since sometimes android doesn't like .ttf files which are accepted by other programs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you create a right TTF font file, its possible to load it to use it in your app.

Just copy the font file to asset folder (if don't exist, create it at the root of your project) and run this code to load it:

```
TypeFace font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myCustomFont.ttf");
```

Then, you can use it in any View:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTypeFace(font);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a ttf file in your project just add it in **assets** folder of your project. And then you can use that font on your activity as :-

```
Typeface font2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "FUTURALC.TTF");
    tv.setTypeface(font2);
```

And I think android would not be having any problem for self made fonts as long as the extension goes right.